# Indexing columns based on cell value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of race results. I'd like to create a series that takes the last stage position and subtracts that by the average of all the stages before that. Here is a small slice for the df (could have more stages, countries and rows)

```
race_location     stage1_position  stage2_position  stage3_position  number_of_stages
AUS               2.0              2.0              NaN              2
AUS               1.0              5.0              NaN              2
AUS               3.0              4.0              NaN              2
AUS               4.0              8.0              NaN              2
AUS               10.0             6.0              NaN              2
AUS               9.0              7.0              NaN              2
FRA               23.0             1.0              10.0             3
FRA               6.0              12.0             24.0             3
FRA               14.0             11.0             14.0             3
FRA               18.0             10.0             1.0              3
FRA               15.0             14.0             4.0              3
USA               24.0             NaN              NaN              1
USA               7.0              NaN              NaN              1
USA               22.0             NaN              NaN              1
USA               11.0             NaN              NaN              1
USA               8.0              NaN              NaN              1
USA               16.0             NaN              NaN              1
USA               13.0             NaN              NaN              1
USA               19.0             NaN              NaN              1
USA               5.0              NaN              NaN              1
USA               25.0             NaN              NaN              1
```

The output would be

```
last_stage_minus_average
0
4
1
4
-4
-2
-2
15
1.5             
-13            
-10.5           
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

This wont work, but I was thinking something like this:

```
new_series = []
for country in country_list:

    num_stages = df.loc[df['race_location'] == country, 'number_of_stages']

    differnce = df.ix[df['race_location'] == country, num_stages] -
        df.iloc[:, 0:num_stages-1].mean(axis=1)

    new_series.append(difference)
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Any help or direction would be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#use pandas apply to take the mean for the first n-1 stages and subtract from last stage.
df.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[x.number_of_stages]-np.mean(x.iloc[1:x.number_of_stages]),axis=1).fillna(0)
Out[264]: 
0      0.0
1      4.0
2      1.0
3      4.0
4     -4.0
5     -2.0
6     -2.0
7     15.0
8      1.5
9    -13.0
10   -10.5
11     0.0
12     0.0
13     0.0
14     0.0
15     0.0
16     0.0
17     0.0
18     0.0
19     0.0
20     0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you! How the dataframe is set up I had to use 
   int(x.number_of_stages)
instead of just 
    x.number_of_stages

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `filter` to get just he stage columns, then `stack` and `groupby`

```
stages = df.filter(regex='^stage\d+.*')

stages.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(
    lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[:-1].mean()
).fillna(0)

0      0.0
1      4.0
2      1.0
3      4.0
4     -4.0
5     -2.0
6     -2.0
7     15.0
8      1.5
9    -13.0
10   -10.5
11     0.0
12     0.0
13     0.0
14     0.0
15     0.0
16     0.0
17     0.0
18     0.0
19     0.0
20     0.0
dtype: float64
```

---

***how it works***

- `stack` will automatically drop the `NaN` values when converting to a series.
- Now, position `-1` is the last value within each group if we grouped by the first level of the new multiindex
- So, we use a `lambda` and calculate the mean with every thing up to the last value `x.iloc[:-1].mean()`
- And subtract that from the last value `x.iloc[-1]`

Comment: I went with the other answer because sometimes there are riders who don't finish all the stages which means that even though the race has 3 stages, the rider might only have two recorded giving him a difference value when he shouldn't have one. Thanks for your answer! Taught me something new!

Comment: @EliotJackson yes!  This answer accounts for that. That is why I got the same results.  That is why I explained as much in my post. When I stack, it drops the stages in which no record exists. If you misunderstood this, please reconsider your choice.

Answer (score 0):

> subtracts that by the average of all the stages before that

It's not a big deal but I'm just curious! Unlike your desired output but along to your description, if one of the racers finished only one race, shouldn't  their result be inf or nan instead of 0? (to specify them from the one who has already done 2~3 race but last race result is exactly same with average of races? like racer #1 vs racer #11~20)

```
df_sp = df.filter(regex='^stage\d+.*')
df['last'] = df_sp.T.fillna(method='ffill').T.iloc[:, -1]
df['mean'] = (df_sp.sum(axis=1) - df['last']) / (df['number_of_stages'] - 1)
print(df['last'] - df['mean'])

0      0.0
1      4.0
2      1.0
3      4.0
4     -4.0
5     -2.0
6     -2.0
7     15.0
8      1.5
9    -13.0
10   -10.5
11     NaN
12     NaN
13     NaN
14     NaN
15     NaN
16     NaN
17     NaN
18     NaN
19     NaN
20     NaN
```

Comment: That's a great point! The way the dataframe is set up, each different race_location is a different race entirely and not all the racers go to each race. 
I guess the question would be if that race only had one stage, should we give a rider the same consistency score (0 for finishing the same as his average) for races with one stage vs races with 8+ stages.